# Jupyter notebook output cell syntax highlighting

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter notebook (IPython on Python 2.7).

I'd like to show some XML content dynamically, like:

```
print dom.toprettyxml(indent='  ')
```

But it's formatted as plaintext in output cell.

I'd like to show it together with syntax highlighting. Is it possible?

I've come across IPython.display with Markdown, Latex, and several others, but no XML. (HTML was there as well, but it didn't help me).

Regards,
Robert

Update:
Thanks to the feedback I was able to do the task with the following code:

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import XmlLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
import IPython

def display_xml_nice(xml_element):
    formatter = HtmlFormatter()
    xml_indented = xml_element.toprettyxml(indent='  ')
    IPython.display.display(HTML('<style type="text/css">{}</style>{}'.format(
        formatter.get_style_defs('.highlight'),
        highlight(xml_indented, XmlLexer(), formatter))))
```

Comment: You could use the [pygments](http://pygments.org/) library to highlight it. Get HTML output from pygments, and then display it as HTML with `IPython.display.HTML()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marking the code properly as answer.

Thanks to the feedback I was able to do the task with the following code:

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import XmlLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
import IPython

def display_xml_nice(xml_element):
    formatter = HtmlFormatter()
    xml_indented = xml_element.toprettyxml(indent='  ')
    IPython.display.display(HTML('<style type="text/css">{}</style>    {}'.format(
    formatter.get_style_defs('.highlight'),
    highlight(xml_indented, XmlLexer(), formatter))))
```

Thank you,
Robert

Comment: Built-in support available IPython.display.Code

Answer (score 0):

As [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448081/jay) mentioned, you can also use `IPython.display.Code` but this will work well only if you're using Jupyter Notebook.

```py
from IPython.display import Code
Code('print("Hello World")', language='python')
```

When using Jupyter Lab though it won't run as expected, as documented in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11747), so you'll need to run the following bit to get it working:

```py
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
from IPython.core.display import HTML

formatter = HtmlFormatter()

display(HTML(f'<style>{ formatter.get_style_defs(".highlight") }</style>'))
```